# "Common Algorithm" Error Despite Forcing TLS 1.2 in .Net 4.7.2 with SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssl, tls1.2

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that is connecting to a SQL Server 2016 database. When I attempt to query the database, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was
> successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
> during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The
> client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a
> common algorithm.)

This seems like a TLS issue and I've seen many posts about how to resolve it. In particular, I tried adding this to the `OnApplicationStarted` function (one of the places you run startup code for Umbraco websites):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I also upgraded the website to target .Net 4.7.2 (was 4.6.x). I did this both on the "Target framework" of the Visual Studio projects as well as in the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="51200" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,:,\,?" executionTimeout="600" fcnMode="Single" />
```

I also fiddled with some registry values (wasn't able to test those fully just yet, but shouldn't need them I would think).

## Stack Trace

Here's a more complete stack trace for your reference:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

## The Weird Part

Here's the weird part: I created a separate Windows Forms application to test the connection from the same production server and it worked perfectly fine!

The target framework for the Windows Forms app was also 4.7.2. Here's the test code from that app:

```
private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var strConn = txtConnection.Text;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(txtQuery.Text, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            gridResults.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I see the SQL results in the grid exactly as I'd expect. It's just the website that doesn't work.

I even tried the test app with and without the following line and it worked either way:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

**Why would I be getting the "client and server cannot communicate" error message from the website, but not from a test app on the same server?**

Comment: Please add to your question the  following: (1) code that makes connection to a DB, (2) What driver is in use to make an actual connection?

Comment: Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/step-3-connect-sql-ado-net?view=sql-server-ver15 and compare your connection string.

Comment: Both the app and the website are using a pretty standard connection string (redacted a couple things): "Server=SomeServerByIpAddress;Database=SomeDb;User ID=SomeUserId;Password=SomePassword".

Comment: The question already shows the code I'm using to connect to the database. The Windows Forms app and the web app do not differ in their code to connect (i.e., they both us "new SqlConnection(strConn)" using the appropriate connection string).

Comment: Please try IIS Crypto on the Web server: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

Comment: Thanks, IIS Crypto looks like it's worth a shot. I'll try it once I resolve some unrelated issues that are preventing me from trying that immediately.

Comment: Try check out this URL which has listing framework TLS Support information

https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tls-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: When you tried your test app with and without `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` was it separate compilations/executions? Once you apply that setting it persists for the runtime of the executable.

Comment: @ThomsonMixab FYI, my question outlines all the details suggested by that article, so that won't help me.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, I rebuilt the solution on my local, then copied the new binaries to prod. In the case of the website, it restarted as expected. In the case of the test app, it was in a new folder, so I was sure it was the new executable.